# Perspective projection based on 4 points in 2D

Tags: computer-vision, rendering, perspective, homography

I'm writing to ask about homography and perspective projection.

I'm trying to write a piece of code, that will "warp" my image so that its corners align with 4 reference points that are in the 3D space - however, the *game engine* that I'm running it in, already allows me to get the screen position of them, so I already have their screen-space coordinates of both xi,yi and ui,vi, normalized to values between 0 and 1.

I have to mention that I don't have a degree in mathematics, which seems to be a requirement in the posts I've seen on this topic so far, but I'm hoping there is actually a solution to this problem that one can comprehend. I never had a chance to take classes in Computer Vision.

The reason I came here is that in all the posts I've seen online, the simple explanation that I came across is that each point must be put into a 1x3 matrix and multiplied by a 3x3 homography, which consists of 9 components h1,h2,h3...h9, and this transformation matrix will transform each point to the correct perspective. And that's where I'm hitting a brick wall - how do I calculate the transformation matrix? It feels like it should be a relatively simple algebraic task, but apparently it's not.

At this point I spent days reading on the topic, and the solutions I've come across are either based on matlab (which have a ton of mathematical functions built into them), or include elaborations and discussions that don't really explain much; sometimes they suggest tons of different parameters and simplifications, but rarely explain why and what's their purpose, or they are referencing books and studies that have been since removed from the web, and I found myself more confused than I was in the beginning. Most of the resources I managed to find online are also made in a different context - image stitching and 3d engine development.

I also want to mention that I need to run this code each frame on the CPU, and I'm fairly concerned about the effect of having to run too many matrix transformations and solving a ton of linear algebra equations.

I apologize for not asking about any specific code, but my general question is - can anyone point me in the right direction with this issue?

Comment: Sadly I can't use a library - the language I'm using for this project doesn't have any for that. I could technically try and write an extension which adds it, but it's probably going to be more effort than it's worth.

Comment: **"game engine"**? then just slap your picture on two triangles in space, as a texture, and draw the thing? I don't get the challenge in that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz right? It's a bit more complex than that, it's for a game mod and the functionalities that it has don't let me paint on a 3D surface, but it's all fine if it's on the screen space.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the problem you deal with.

For example, if you always warp the entire rectangular image, you can treat that the coordinates of the image corners are {(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)}.
This can simplify the equation, and you'll be able to solve the equation by yourself.
So you'll be able to implement the answer.

Note : Homograpy is scale invariant. So you can decrease the freedom to 8. (e.g. you can solve the equation under h9=1).

Comment: Thanks, you were right on that 0-1 approach, it made the solution soooo much easier, and the code actually worked on the first try

Comment: I'm coming back to the discussion with some extra concern.
When I supplied the {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)} points to the matrix and solved it, I indeed got all the h1..h8 parameters, but what really surprised me is that none of the resulting equations actually take the 4th point (1,1) into account - they only reference x1, x2, x3 and y1,y2,y3. As a result, the perspective transformation looks good when I look at it head on, but when I move the players POV to the side, it gets distorted and warped to a rectangle (the bottom right corner, (1,1), just kinda follows the other ones). Any ideas?

Comment: I tried little with paper and pen... At first, I could obtain h3 and h5 from (0,0) point only.
But after that, it looks like I can't solve it without using all the other 3 points...

Comment: I considered a coordinate system with one point on the transformed side as the origin (0,0), and I could easily obtain two more elements.
For example, h1 and h4 can be obtained from 2nd warpped point=(0,0).
At this point, there are four unknowns remaining, and four equations (for 3rd and 4th points). So I think we need to use all points.

Comment: typo > "At first, I could obtain h3 and h5"  :   should be h3 and *h6*

Comment: maybe Im doing something wrong then... from my calculations, h7 and h8 are 0, and then h9 is 1, so it ends up being an affine transformation, which isnt accurate in my case.

Comment: From my calculations:
x' = (x3 + x2 - x1) * x;
y' = (y3 + y2 - y1) * y;

Where (x',y') is the final transformed point, and (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) are the positions of the edges of the target transformation; (x,y) is the coordinate of the point before transition from 0 to 1 on both x and y axis. This comes from the fact that
h1 = x3-x1;
h2 = x2 - x1;
h3 = x1;
And the same story for the y1..y3.
No x4 and y4 came out of the equation :( Although maybe I should start calculating the matrix from that :(

Answer (score 1):

Best advice I can give: read a good book on the subject. For example, "Multiple View Geometry" by Hartley and Zisserman